# D3.js - Conditional apply nest.key() function to array elements

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I have a CSV that represents a hierarchical tree data:

```
industry,level1,level2,level3,name
Ecommerce,Web,,,Rakuten
Ecommerce,Crowdsourcing,,,Lancers
Social,Photo sharing,Deco apps,,Snapeee
Social,Photo sharing,Deco apps,Collage apps,DecoAlbum
Portals,,,,Yahoo Japan
```

Rows `level1...level3` represent children nodes, and row `name` represents the bottom node. I am trying to apply `d3.nest()` function, to get a hierarchical JSON object. In particular, I want to get rid of nodes where level rows are empty. So far I have following code:

```
d3.csv("data.csv", function(rows) {
  sunburst_tree = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) { return d.industry; })
    .key(function(d) { return d.level1; })
    .key(function(d) {  if (!(typeof d.level2 === 'undefined')) return d.level2; })
    .entries(rows);

  console.log(sunburst_tree);
});
```

Which produces JSON object with empty keys, like this:

```
{"key":"Portals",
"values":[{"key":"",
    "values":[{"key":"",
        "values":[{"industry":"Portals","level1":"","level2":"","level3":"","name":"Yahoo Japan"}]
        }]
    }]
}
```

Instead I'd like to drop all empty sub-nodes:

```
{"key":"Portals",
    "values":[{"industry":"Portals",
               "level1":"","level2":"","level3":"","name":"Yahoo Japan"}]}
}
```

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to have multiple keys? Seems like in your desired format you have just one key.

In case you don't want multiple keys, you should remove your functions that define the keys,

OR

In case you do want multiple keys, i would recommend having an if clause before you use your function for generating the key. And checking for empty string as

```
d.level1 === ""
```

should help.